# Unable to connect AWS Elasticsearch from Fargate. Getting java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I have a Spring Boot image deployed using AWS Fargate and the Elasticsearch cluster using AWS Elasticsearch Service.
Both are under same VPC and subnet. Below is the access policy of Elasticsearch:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:ap-south-1:8655488xxxxx:domain/website-qa/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Security groups:
Fargate: `sg-test033f776d5fbed5c0000`
Elasticsearch: `sg-test0e5a570cbfc389e8555`

Subnet:
Fargate: `subnet-test025f49153cf245a2d11,subnet-test01f19783c005010f122,subnet-test076dfbba51d92d49033`
Elasticsearch: `ap-south-1a: subnet-test025f49153cf245a2d11`

Under the security group of elasticsearch, I have allowed the security group of Fargate for port `443` and `9200`.

And below is from application.yml file:

```
spring:
  elasticsearch:
    rest:
      connection-timeout: 5000 #milliseconds
      read-timeout: 5000 #milliseconds
      uris: https://vpc-website-qa-xxxxxxxxxxxx.ap-south-1.es.amazonaws.com:9200
```

So spring boot tries to make a connection to Elasticsearch but get `java.net.UnknownHostException https://vpc-website-qa-xxxxxxxxxxxx.ap-south-1.es.amazonaws.com:9200`

Tried with port `443` also but didn't work. Why host is not resolved at Fargate cluster? What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you have DNS support, and DNS hostnames enabled on your VPC? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html

Comment: @MarkB Yes this is already enabled.

Comment: @TheCoder You should first check if you are able to resolve the given DNS entry from within the VPC, Just start a new EC2 instance and do an "nslookup" or a "dig" and see if the IP address for the cluster's nodes are resolved correctly. You have to localize the error and find out where the misconfiguration took place,,, Probably somewhere on the dns layer...

Comment: As others said, first check if you can connect to ES form EC2 instance or any other way, just to confirm that the issue is only related to fargate.

Comment: Yes, I am checking it from ec2. Iam able to curl the vpc endpoint, but java is still giving the same error. Seems like a library issue.

Comment: Why do you use port 9200? ES only works on port 443 or 80. By the way, you have to @Marcin tag, if you reply in comments. Otherwise ppl do not get notifications about your replies.

Comment: @Marcin I used `443` port and removed the `https` and it worked. Thanks for your help

Comment: Glad it worked. If you don't mind I will provide an answer.

Comment: @Marcin please do :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments.

ES does not use `9200` port. Only ports 80 for http and https on port 443 are supported. [From docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-vpc.html):

> Amazon ES only accepts connections over port **80 (HTTP) or 443 (HTTPS)**.

Also `spring-data-elasticsearch` expects only the domain, so `https` should not be used.

Removing `https` and using port `443` resolved the issue.

`uris: vpc-website-qa-xxxxxxxxxxxx.ap-south-1.es.amazonaws.com:443`